# Python language support for pipes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I would like to implement in python something like this:

```
def producer():
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("this is my data\n")

def consumer():
    while True:
        data = sys.stdin.read()
        print data

producer | consumer
```

The pipe actually needs to create two processes, connect stdout and stdin, and run them until both terminate.

Is there syntactical support for that in python, as the shell has, or do I need to recurse to the `Popen` object?

What is the simplest implementation in terms of `Popen`?

Could somebody offer a generic class which can be used to implement this piping pattern? The class would have a signature similar to this:

```
Class Pipe:

    def __init__(self, process1, process2, ...):
```

So that, in my case, could be used as follows:

```
mypipe = Pipe(producer, consumer)
```

Comment: can't you pass the `sys.stdin` file object as an argument? If you can just use files or pipes.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: since `sys.stdin` and  `sys.stdout` are a file objects like any other, maybe your producer declaration can be something like this `def producer(output=sys.stdout)` and your consumer `def consumer(input=sys.stdin)` and you use `output.write("this is my data")` and `data = input.read()` in the producer/consumer code.

Comment: If you have two pieces of Python code, why must they print to stdout and read from stdin? Can't you just write them to accept and return iterables?

Comment: Sure, they can accept and return iterables. I still need to connect them in a generic way, though. I mean, the Pipe class must be generic enough so that it can accept any python function. It is responsability of the programmer to make sure that what goes out of the first function can be piped to the second function. The important thing is that both functions must run concurrently, in two processes. And, unless it is put in the background (maybe a special flag for that would be interesting), the interpreter must block theere until both processes have completed.

Comment: Sorry for all the rubish I have been writing. I was referring to threads and not processes, so forget everything I said about Popen. It must be implemented with Thread, but I do not know how to change stdin / stdout of a thread. Anyway, the proper way to do this seems to be _couroutines_, as pointed out by Paul McGuire. I have not tried it, but seems promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be thinking of *coroutines*.  Check out this [very interesting presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html) by David Beazley.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/pipes.html) module:

> The pipes module defines a class to abstract the concept of a pipeline — a sequence of converters from one file to another.

Sure, the syntax won't be the same as a shell pipe, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Mmmm ... The "processes" which I want to start are python functions which have been imported, not executables

Comment: The `pipes` module is not concerned with the origin of the data to be piped (processes, functions, etc.) as long as data gets written to / read from the standard input/output/error streams

Comment: Not sure about that: "Template.append: The cmd variable must be a valid bourne shell command". Maybe you mean `Pipe` from the `multiprocessing` module?